# Error downloading Html using HtmlAgilityPack Library in C#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Trying to scrape this [Website](https://www.finedininglovers.com/recipes/appetizer/vegan-dishes-white-asparagus/) but unable to do it..

It throws an exception with the message has `Error downloading Html`

[image]

C# Code

```
    async public static Task<HtmlDocument> GetDocument()
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = null;
        string url = "https://www.finedininglovers.com/recipes/appetizer/vegan-dishes-white-asparagus/";
        try
        {
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            doc = await web.LoadFromWebAsync(url);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
        return doc;
    }
```

Tried setting `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7` as the UserAgent but still not working

Comment: @Daniel its not a null issue and the link which you have shared is related to null exception but in my case thats not the issue since I have specifically said for 1 particular website it isn't working

Comment: i see that error in your console.

Comment: its an exception being thrown when `LoadFromWebAsync` is called.
Same code gets the result for other website links but the link which I have posted doesn't work

Comment: @Sharath Don't waste your time with HtmlAgilityPack, it's old and broken - use [AngleSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/anglesharp/) instead. As a bonus, AngleSharp has no problem scraping that page. :)

Comment: @DanielA.White The NullRef is being thrown by HtmlAgilityPack, not the code posted. So the issue is a bug in HAP.

Comment: @LanKemp 70% of code already written using HAP and need to check it if its a bug from HAP

Comment: @Sharath Since it's a bug in HAP and you've already [submitted an issue to them](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/issues/171), maybe add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue is created here [Link](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/issues/171)

Below code works as mentioned in the github link.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = null;
string url = "your_link";

HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
doc = web.Load(url);
var html = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```